# Responsive Grid Listview jquery mobile for 1.4.5v

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

there is  a demo for Responsive Grid Listview for 1.3.0 version (Jquery mobile)

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ggzHT/74/

but it do not work for 1.4.5v with these resource:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to support it?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: with replace new resource (js and css for 1.4.5v)  with old one, the list view is not work.

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/ggzHT/76/  works for me.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi  please change width of documents for jsfiddle.net/ggzHT/74 demo. it has two kind of view. also if you add js (1.4.5v) to jsfiddle.net/ggzHT/76 it show wrong that list!

Answer (score 0):

The 1.4.5 demo link below. Just view the page source

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-grid/listview-grid.html